# C++ operations on nested enums

Tags: c++, enums, nested, operator-keyword

I have several nested enums similar to the following.  I want to have an `isValid()` function defined as close as possible to the `enum` definition.  Actual code is more verbose with multiple levels of nested namespaces and structs.

```
struct S
{
    enum E { V1, V2 };
    /* ????? */ bool isValid(E e) { return e==V1 || e==V2; }
};

template <typename Enum>
bool legalValue(Enum e)
{  
    return isValid(e);
}
```

Is it possible to make this code work without having to place `isValid()` in the global namespace?

Please don't comment on whether `isValid()` is good practice.  This question is just as applicable for someone wanting to override `operator<<()` to be able to stream enum values meaningfully.  In that case, is there any way the essence of `operator<<()` can be located within the body of `struct S`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here.  Just make the `isValid()` function `static`, and change the `legalValue()` function to do `return S::isValid(e);`, and I think this should compile...

Comment: The idea is that `legalValue<Enum>()` should work for any `enum` that has an associated `isValid()` function.  It doesn't work for enums nested with `class` or `struct`.

Comment: Try putting the enum inside a namespace, instead of a struct. This way, ADL should kick in (I have not tested it), and you should be able to call isValid no matter in where namespace the enum is declared.

Comment: In my case, the natural home is inside a `struct`.

Comment: Ah ok.  So, more generally, you have code like `struct S { enum E; bool foo(E); }; struct T { enum F; bool foo(F); };`.  You want a template that will do the "correct" thing given either `S::E` or `T::F`?

Comment: There is no way of getting the surrounding class, where the enum is defined, which means there is no way of knowing which `isValid` to call.

Comment: Will the enum always be called `E` inside the struct?  Could you parameterise your template on the struct type instead?

Comment: @paperjam: `In my case, the natural home is inside a struct` : Then try putting the function outside the struct, with its parameter being `S::E` instead of plain `E`.

Comment: No offense intended, @paperjam, but your questions reads as a bit overly defensive to me.  Instead of saying `Please don't comment on whether isValid() is good practice`, it would sound more friendly to say something such as `I am aware that some may question whether isValid() is good practice...`  One of the issues you have to deal with a public question and answer site is that you don't really have control over what people want to answer or what aspect of your question they will latch onto, and attempting to pre-emptively restrict that might work counter to your interests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you'll have to move `isValid` out of the `struct`. The `enum` definition can stay inside it, though.

```
struct S
{
    enum E { V1, V2 };
};

bool isValid(S::E e) { return e == S::V1 || e == S::V2; }

template <typename Enum>
bool legalValue(Enum e)
{
    return isValid(e);
}
```

Comment: One of the OP's stipulations was "Is it possible to make this code work without having to place isValid() in the global namespace?"...

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking if there's a solution other than this.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: and I guess the answer is no; updated the answer, although I can't cite chorus and verse from the Standard.

Comment: @paperjam: why _would_ you want an answer other than this?  Were you just hoping for another possibility since you'd already thought of this?

Comment: Because I have deeply nested structs and I want `isValid()` to be close to the enum definition.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to find `S` from `S::E`.

If `S` were a namespace, [Koenig lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) would find `isValid` even if it is not part of the global namespace, but I think that's not what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for standard C++, i.e. for C++2011, you could forward declare the nested enumeration:

```
struct S { enum E: int; };

enum S::E: int { V1, V2 };
bool isValid(S::E e) { return e == S::V1 || S::V2; }
```

Of course, you also wouldn't need to nest the enumeration into a struct to avoid pollution of the enclosing scope: instead you'd use

```
enum class S { V1, V2 };
bool isValid(S e) { return e == S::V1 || S::V2; }
```

Using `V1` or `V2` unqualified would be illegal.

Answer (score 1):

These might be technical points, but another option from making `isValid` global is to overload (or specialize)`legalValue`.

```
struct S
{
    enum E { V1, V2 };
    static bool isValid(E e) { return e==V1 || e==V2; }
};
bool legalValue(S::E e) { return S::isValid(e); }

template <typename Enum>
bool legalValue(Enum e) { return isValid(e); }
```

Another option is to make `isValid` a global friend.  Though this differs in almost no way from it just being a free global function.

```
struct S
{
    enum E { V1, V2 };
    friend bool isValid(E e) { return e==V1 || e==V2; }
};
template <typename Enum>
bool legalValue(Enum e) { return isValid(e); }
```